# Memcached can not listen on a port different from 11211 in Alma Linux 8.8

Tags: linux, port, memcached, centos8

I installed successfully Memcached in Alma Linux 8.8 (a Red Hat 8.8 clone) but, when I changed the port number from 11211 to 11212 in the config file at /etc/sysconfig/memcached and restarted the service, I got the following message:

> failed to listen on TCP port 11212: Permission denied

Other port numbers (11213, 11214, etc.) don't work either!

I am running a Vagrant machine (downloaded from the official repository of Alma Linux) on VirtualBox 7.0.8

Updates: after reading asktyagi note, I changed the port  number to 11213 and restarted the service. I've got this on cockpit:

> **SELinux access control errors**
>
> SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/memcached from name_bind access on the
> tcp_socket port 11213.
>
> *Solution*: If you want to allow /usr/bin/memcached to bind to network port 11213
> you need to modify the port type.
>
> *Solution details*: semanage port -a -t memcache_port_t -p tcp 11213
>
> *Audit log*:
>
> type=AVC msg=audit(1690420222.524:28): avc: denied { name_bind } for pid=778 comm="memcached" src=11213 scontext=system_u:system_r:memcached_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unreserved_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0

Comment: What audit or secure logs says?

Comment: Hi. I changed the port number to 11213 and caught some new messages. I will update the post with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux is preventing port to bind. Execute below command to allow it from selinux side.

`semanage port -a -t memcache_port_t -p tcp 11213`

Other way is disable selinux, relabel it and retry.

Comment: I executed the command suggested for ports 11212, 11213, 11214 and 11215 and it worked!